# How to pass csv file as query param in api call using powershell

Tags: database, powershell, api, query-string

I have developed two simple PS scripts that work fine separately. Script1 connects to a DB, run a sql query and save the output (only one column that is a list of the project names) as csv file. Script2 connects to an endpoint using API calls and prints the details of a projects. I use script1's output as script2's input manually. I have tried a couple of different ways to automate this process but I haven't been able to get it to work. Does anyone know how can I pass the csv file as query param in api call?

Here is what I have so far:

This is Script1:

```
#SQL Connection variables
$Server = "my server"
$DBName = "db name"
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path  "C:\Test\MyCredential.xml"
$User = $Credential.UserName
$PW = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Server; Database = $DBName; User ID = $User; Password = $PW;"

$Connection.Open()
#$Connection.State

$SqlQuery = "select from table example"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$CxSqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0

 #Creating sql adapter
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 

#Creating Dataset  
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet  
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
$DataSet.Tables[0] | export-csv -Path $OuputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The output for script 1 is 11223344, So I use this project name as my input or query param in my second script.

And this is Script2:

```
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path  "C:\Test\MyCredential2.xml"
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path  "C:\Test\MyCredential2.xml"
$APIKEY = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$token = "APIKEY " + "$APIKEY"



$Params = @{
uri = 'https:myendpoint/search?name=11223344'
Headers = @{'Authorization' = "API KEY $token"}
Method ='GET'
ContentType = 'application/json'
}

$Response = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

I really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Make these separate scripts a single script as two functions, where function 2 (your script 2) will consume results from function 1 (your script 1)

Comment: I ended up doing this: instead of saving the output into a csv file, I stored them in a variable ($Results). I made my second script a new function and passed this as its parameter. (e.i. Function getAppId ($Results))

Comment: @postanote Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Good work and no worries. We are here to help when and with what we can.